# "Saying/doing it from your heart" vs. "Saying/doing it from heart"

Tags: differences, articles, possessives

What is the difference between the following two?

> They didn't play the game from *their* heart.
>
> They didn't play the game from heart.

Or

> You didn't say that from your heart
>
> You didn't say that from heart

Comment: I wonder if the other phrase being compared here was meant to be "know something by heart".

Answer (score 3):

'Doing something *from heart*' is not a phrase I have ever heard, and I don't believe it's good English. Doing it *from the heart* is the usual phrase.  Doing it *from your heart* is uncommon, but probably not rare enough to be unidiomatic; there is no real difference between that and *from the heart*.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there's some idiom here that I'm not familiar with, but to the best of my knowledge, leaving out the "the" is simply wrong. The word "heart" requires an article (or some other subsitute adjective).

Comment: Agreed - the standard idiom is [played from **the** heart](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22played+from+the+heart%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). OP could just about get away with *"You've got to play it from **your** heart"*, but it's nearly always *"the"*.

Answer (score 2):

The first idiom, *Y Do X From Y's Heart,* is OK.

The second one, *Y Do X From Heart,* is ungrammatical.
It should be: *Y Do X From **The** Heart,*

> *They didn't play the game from **the** heart.*

The definite article is part of the idiom, and both idioms mean the same thing.

Whose heart should they play from, after all, if not their own heart(s)?

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like when you're doing something from the heart means you doing it by pity while doing it with the heart shows that you're doing it with passion.

DS

Answer (score 0):

I think DOING SMTH FROM THE HEART and DOING SMTH FROM YOUR HEART have same meaning. But i always use the first option, for example, if we say /YOU ALWAYS DO EVERYTHING FROM THE HEART/ - we have there YOU we can know whom we are saying and so we must not define whose heart from.
but also if you want to place emphasis you can use possessive pronouns with HEART.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).